# understanding $0 < f(a_n) \to f(x_0)$ implies $f(x_0) \ge 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I have two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ over the interval $[a, b]$ where $a_n$ is monotonically increasing, $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

Also 
$$x_0=\lim_{n}a_n=\lim_{n}b_n$$

I'm trying to understand why $0 < f(a_n) \to f(x_0)$ implies $f(x_0) \ge 0$,

where $f$ is a continuous function defined over the interval $[a, b]$ and $f(a) > 0, f(b) < 0$.

Comment: Consider the sequence $\frac 1 n$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: Taking limits on an inequality weakens the inequality. Thus even if the given inequality is strict the limits may be equal. At the root of this is the simple observation that there can be be sequences where each term is non-zero (or positive) and yet the limit is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

> If $a_n>b \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_n \to a$ then $a \geq b$.

$Proof$

> Assume that $a_n \to a$ and $a<b$.
>
> Then for $\epsilon=b-a>0$ exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-a|< b-a$
>
> Thus $a_n<b-a+a=b$ forall $n \geq n_0$ which is a contradiction.
>
> Thus $a \geq b$

I hope this helps you to understand why $f(x_0) \geq 0$

Also  if $a_n<b \in \mathbb{R}$  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_n \to a$ then $a \leq b$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the proof even though it's a bit hard for me to picture it visually.

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov....if you understand the definition of convergence of a sequence $a_n$ using intervals of the form $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ where $a$ is the limit then you will understand  also. this proof in an instant i believe

Comment: With the word ''understand'' i mean intuitively and formally